# Faild to create a db connection etween NetBeans and sql server

Tags: java, sql-server

I have tried to connect the netbeans to sql server

my sql server name is: `BELL\BELLISQLSERVER`

and the user name is: `BELL\1`

I saw many tutorials but every time I've got the same error massage it says: `login faild for user 'BELL\1'`

A screen shoot of the error message I have got:
[image: screen shoot]

Comment: can you connect to this SQL Server using SSMS?

Comment: yes I used SSMS to connect to sql server

Comment: Ok. The message **'login faild for user 'BELL\1''** is from NetBeans. What is the error message in SQL Server log? You can access it opening SSMS > BELLISQLSERVER > Management > SQL Server Logs > Current.

Comment: The massage- Login failed for user 'NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster140'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: That's strange. I think some other service tried to connect to SQL Server by the time you tested the connection and this log message is from the other service. I'll propose a solution rather than keep trying to troubleshoot your connection test.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of connection to SQL Server. You'll notice some differences from yours.

[image: NetBeans Connection Wizard]

The driver I'm using is [Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.4 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58505), but you can keep the one you're using if you wish.

The Host is **just** the name of the server in which SQL Server Instance is installed. It should be **BELL** in your case.

Port is the default 1433 and you need to ensure TCP/IP is enabled and configured. To do so run `sqlservermanager14.msc` and check if it's like this:

[image]

Instance Name is the name of your SQL Server service. Mine is SQL2017 and yours is **BELLISQLSERVER**.

The user name you specified is a *NT user account* and I'm not sure it's possible to use one for that NetBeans wizard. Instead I used a SQL Server login that you might create on SSMS like this:

[image: Create login wizard]

To understand login options verify the [Create a Login](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-2017) documentation.

Make sure your instance is configured to accept SQL Server logins by:
Connecting to the instance > Right click the instance name > Properties > Security > choose *Sql Server and Windows Authentication mode* and restart the instance for the change to take effect. Grant the right privileges on the database for the user.

Now I think you're good to go! Test your connection and it should work fine.

Comment: hi Ronaldo, I tried to create a Login like you told me and I got this message: 
The server principal 'BELL\1' already exists. I tried to do everything you told me with this user name but the connection with the NetBeans did not work. so I tried to create a new Login name and I got this message: 'BELLI' is not a valid Windows NT name. Give the complete name: <domain\username>.

Comment: Since you had problems creating the login, I edited the answer to add the wizard for that step. Please check the answer again. You can create the login following those options or even executing this on SSMS:   

`USE [master];
CREATE LOGIN [myuser] WITH PASSWORD=N'@myuserPASSWD', 
 DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
 CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, 
 CHECK_POLICY=ON;`  

After creating this user remember to change your **server authentication** and restarting your server to apply the change, like described.